# glUseProgramObjectARB invalid operation error

Tags: c, opengl, sdl, glsl

I'm getting an "invalid operation" error when trying to use `glUseProgramObjectARB` and I have no idea why.

The shader programs are loading correctly, I'm fairly sure. This is shown on `glGetInfoLogARB`:

- Vertex shader was successfully compiled to run on hardware.
- Fragment shader was successfully compiled to run on this hardware.

There are no previous openGL errors before this command. So something with this specific command definitely appears to be the issue.

I'm using glew with SDL. I was using GLee before, and getting the same problem.

Reading the [documentation](http://www.opengl-doc.com/Addison.Wesley-OpenGL.Shading1/0321197895/app02lev1sec24.html) I assume it is this error:

> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if program could not be made part of current state.

but I'm not sure exactly what could cause such a thing. The command is issued in a working openGL context, as all the previous shader commands work fine. It is not between a "begin" and "end" block.

Really I am stumped as to what it could mean. Perhaps there is some more specific case when the command can't be issued. If anyone knows anything more that would be great.

EDIT:

Solved: oh jesus that was retarded, I was missing a return on one of my function calls elsewhere and so wasn't passing back the program I'd constructed.

Comment: I see your info logs are OK, but have the objects/program actually compiled/linked correctly? (glGetObjectiv(GL_COMPILE_STATUS), glGetProgramiv(GL_LINK_STATUS)). I know some scenarios of the program failing to link despite the same "good" info log it produces.

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing your code it's hard to know, but since you explicitly mention the results of `glCompileShaderARB` (times two) but not `glLinkProgramARB` I will guess that you forgot to `glLinkProgramARB` (after which, by the way, you can safely `glDeleteObjectARB` the two shader objects).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did link the program without issues, didn't know I could delete the shader objects after linking though. The code is hard to paste as it is fairly encapsulated in some extra objects, but here is in short what I am executing:

http://pastebin.com/w9G1KiWd